# Windows powershell syntax to import a text file , strip a field and export it into different file

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to import a text file, limiting a particular field to hold 800 characters and then exporting the data into a file using windows powershell.

I know how to do but not sure about the syntax. Please find below the script I came up with but it is not working as expected.

Kindly suggest the proper syntax.

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter `t E:\Server_Data\Unstructured\DCDOR\DCDOR_2015_07.txt | Select-Object business_format_date,business_time,room,guest_full_name,trx_code,trx_desc,currency1,cashier_debit,cashier_credit,@{Name="Derived"; Expression={$_.Reference.Substring(0,if($_.Reference.Length -lt 800) {$_.Reference.Length} else {800)}}; | Export-CSV -Delimiter `t E:\Server_Data\Unstructured\DCDOR\DCDOR_2015_07_Target.txt;
```

Error Message

```
At line:1 char:262
+ ... ce.Substring(0,if($_.Reference.Length -lt 800) {$_.Reference.Length} else {800}) ...
+                    ~
Missing expression after ','.
At line:1 char:262
+ ... ce.Substring(0,if($_.Reference.Length -lt 800) {$_.Reference.Length} else {800}) ...
+                    ~~
Unexpected token 'if' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:236
+ ... d"; Expression={$_.Reference.Substring(0,if($_.Reference.Length -lt 800) {$_.Ref ...
+                    ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At line:1 char:326
+ ... gth} else {800})}}; | Export-CSV -Delimiter `t E:\Server_Data\Unstructured\DCDOR ...
+                    ~
The hash literal was incomplete.
At line:1 char:326
+ ... gth} else {800})}}; | Export-CSV -Delimiter `t E:\Server_Data\Unstructured\DCDOR ...
+                    ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:327
+ ... th} else {800})}}; | Export-CSV -Delimiter `t E:\Server_Data\Unstructured\DCDOR\ ...
+                    ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:328
+ ... h} else {800})}}; | Export-CSV -Delimiter `t E:\Server_Data\Unstructured\DCDOR\D ...
+                    ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:331
+ ... else {800})}}; | Export-CSV -Delimiter `t E:\Server_Data\Unstructured\DCDOR\DCDO ...
+                    ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken
```

Comment: enclose the if statement in a subexpression: `$(if(){}else{})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I formated your script, removed semicolons and changed the expression for the `Derived`column a little bit. It now uses `[System.Math]::Min(800, $_.Reference.Length)`to ensure the string contains max 800 characters instead of a if-else. Give it a try:

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter '`t' 'E:\Server_Data\Unstructured\DCDOR\DCDOR_2015_07.txt' | 
    Select-Object business_format_date,
        business_time,
        room,guest_full_name,
        trx_code,
        trx_desc,
        currency1,
        cashier_debit,
        cashier_credit,
        @{Name="Derived"; Expression={
                $_.Reference.Substring(0, [System.Math]::Min(800, $_.Reference.Length))
            }} | 
        Export-CSV -Delimiter '`t' 'E:\Server_Data\Unstructured\DCDOR\DCDOR_2015_07_Target.txt'
```